# Calculating the size of a room

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I need your help with the following, practical, math problem. Suppose we have a group of $n$ people, which we want to position as the vertices of a equilateral, convex polygon with the length of the edges being $s$. Moreover, we want to fit this polygon inside a rectangular room where the walls have ratio $a:b$. Is there a way we can calculate how big the room should be?

If we consider a square room, this is easy; because the radius of a circle circumscribing a regular polygon can with $n$ vertices and edges of length $s$ can be calculated as the following: $$\frac{s}{2\sin (\frac{\pi}{n})}.$$

However, I do not really know how to start with computing this for the more general case described above. So, any help is welcome!

edit: The equilateral polygon should be convex! I.e., the vertices should look a bit like points on an ellipse.

Comment: Wouldn't it just be the same as fitting the regular polygon inside a square with side length = $\min(a,b)$?

Comment: No, since $a:b$ just describes the ratio between the two sides.

Comment: Well clearly its going to be impossible then since whatever solution you come up with you can just scale the rectangle down by some arbitrarily large factor such that the polygon won't fit.

Comment: Just reread the question and now I understand. My comment still applies though, it should just be the same as the square solution with the smaller side length of the rectangle being the square's side length, no?

Comment: Hang on, what do you mean the vertices of the polygon lie like on an ellipse, don't you mean circle?

Comment: No, I mean an ellipse.The circle is the 'easy' case, but I want to generalize it.

Comment: -1 Not clear what you are asking. If the polygon is irregular then for $n>3$ the shape is not fixed. Are you asking for the largest area of equilateral convex n-gon which can be fitted inside a rectangle $a\times b$? Do the vertices of the n-gon have to lie on an ellipse?